# Book recommendation for a new student on complex analysis

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

Please consider the following topics

1.Analytic functions

2.Cauchy's theorem and Cauchy Integral formula

3.Maximum Modulus Principle

4.Laurent Series

5.Singularities

6.Theory of residues and contour integration

I am new to complex analysis and have to study these.Please suggest some books keeping in mind I have just completed a course in real analysis

Comment: complex analysis by "stein and shakarachi"

Comment: Ahlfors is a pretty standard text (though I'll admit I wish there was a little more "organizational structure", i.e. stated all of his results as theorems/lemmas/etc instead of it all being inline text, which makes it difficult to refer back to easily)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend "[Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540939822) (Universitext)" by Freitag & Busam.

It contains all your requirements and has complete solutions in the back. There is also a second volume if you want to go deeper into the subject.

Comment: I like your choice. I was surprised that there was a section on elliptic modular forms.

Comment: very good book will serve my purpose +1

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Marsden's [Basic Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071672877X) and Bak's [Complex Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=MKPe1Q9k-nAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=joseph+bak+complex+analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZlPKVMGKNMarggTJj4TYDQ&ved=0CCAQ6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=joseph%20bak%20complex%20analysis&f=false). It might help if you have this [Schaum's outline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071615695) on the side to accompany one (or both) of these texts.

Comment: very good book will serve my purpose+1